# Can Parallelism in .Net takes over CPU and may deny services to other processes?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am trying to understand how Parallelism is implemented in .Net. Following code is taken as an example from [Reed Copsey Blog](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-3-imperative-data-parallelism-early-termination/).

This code loops over the customers collection and sends them emails after 14 days since their last contact. My Question here is if the customer table is very BIG and sending an email takes few seconds, will NOT this code takes CPU in Denial of Services mode to other important processes?

Is there a way to run following lines of code in parallel but only using few cores so other processes can share CPU? Or Am i approaching the problem in wrong way?

```
Parallel.ForEach(customers, (customer, parallelLoopState) =>
{
    // database operation
    DateTime lastContact = theStore.GetLastContact(customer); 
    TimeSpan timeSinceContact = DateTime.Now - lastContact;

    // If it's been more than two weeks, send an email, and update...
    if (timeSinceContact.Days > 14)
    {
         // Exit gracefully if we fail to email, since this 
         // entire process can be repeated later without issue.
         if (theStore.EmailCustomer(customer) == false)
             parallelLoopState.Break();
         else
             customer.LastEmailContact = DateTime.Now;
    }
});
```

**Accepted Answer:**

Thought Process was RIGHT! as Cole Campbell pointed out, One can control and configure how many cores should be used by specifying ParallelOption object in this specific example. Here is how.

```
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 
                 Math.Max(Environment.ProcessorCount / 2, 1);
```

And Parallel.ForEach will be used as follow.

```
Parallel.ForEach(customers, parallelOptions, 
                                (customer, parallelLoopState) =>
{
    //do all same stuff
}
```

Same concept can be applied for PLINQ using .WithDegreeOfParallelism(int numberOfThreads).
For more information on how to configure Parallel Options, [read this.](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/02/11/parallelism-in-net-part-9-configuration-in-plinq-and-tpl/)

Comment: It is the job of the operating system to ensure that this doesn't happen.  It gives a fair share of the cores to all threads in all processes.  This kind of code doesn't cause any significant cpu load anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant - Are you sure? Because I ran into full CPU utilization on my laptop and even Mouse move interrupts were not entertained during that time.

Comment: @ImranAmjad High CPU usage by one process is not going to slow down your mouse pointer. Usually when I see that, it means some apps are using too much memory and the machine is [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: @JoeWhite I am running 8 parallel threads on 4 Processor system each running VBA Excel code and all doing heavy computations. Each Excel.exe takes 25% CPU and 60MB memory at max.

Comment: @ImranAmjad That's fine, but unless you're doing something weird like changing process priorities, it shouldn't slow down your mouse pointer. You've got something else weird going on. 100% CPU loads should not mess up your mouse.

Comment: @JoeWhite Just to share interesting fact, I ran my code with ParallelOption to run only 4 out of 8 threads at a time on 4 processor system and OS UI events were responding fine. But When I removed ParallelOption and ran 8 threads, it started all threads at the same time and slowed down system because of context switching is happening that's why it's slowing down OS. I'm not changing threads priorities.

Comment: @ImranAmjad It still sounds more as an I/O issue. Even context switching wouldn't be enough to explain slowed down mouse pointer on its own, especially since the windows UI system has a rather high priority. Unless, of course, your application is starving the kernel (again, this is mostly through I/O operations). Lowering the thread count might have solved your immediate problem, but there's probably still something wrong with your code and / or computer. I'd guess the database operations are to blame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Task Parallelism Library is designed to take the system workload into account when scheduling tasks to run, so this shouldn't be an issue.  However, you can use the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property on the `ParallelOptions` class, which can be passed into one of the overloads of `ForEach()`, to restrict the number of concurrent operations that it can perform, if you really need to.

Comment: I'm not sure `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is actually used by the default scheduler (at least insofar as it might correspond to the maximum number of threads). I believe this scheduler handles it correctly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx

Comment: Thanks Cole! your answer works for me. Also, i found more discussion in another blog [here](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/02/11/parallelism-in-net-part-9-configuration-in-plinq-and-tpl/).

Comment: @ta.speot.is - I just threw together a test that crunches 10 million integers in a parallel foreach loop, and it definitely looks like `MaxDegreeofParallelism` makes a difference.  Failing to specify it spikes 7 of my 8 logical cores to 100%.  Setting it to some value - for example, 2 - significantly reduces CPU utilization, presumably because only 2 of them are running at once.

Comment: The TPL doesn't actually do this.  It disregards other processes, it assumes all cores are available to your process.

Comment: Hans:  Can you cite documentation for this?  I'm going by what it says on MSDN:  "When a parallel loop runs, the TPL partitions the data source so that the loop can operate on multiple parts concurrently. Behind the scenes, the Task Scheduler partitions the task based on system resources and workload. When possible, the scheduler redistributes work among multiple threads and processors if the workload becomes unbalanced."

Comment: I would have to second Cole Campbell. MaxDegreeofParallelism works. But By default, PLINQ will occasionally revert to processing a query in parallel to avoid performance degrade. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997399(VS.100).aspx).